# Cannot get the length of JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have read other issues regarding accessing a json array in javascript, but nothing helped in my case.
I am receiving the below json in jquery ajax call.

```
{"jList":"[{\"added_by\":\"Ani\",\"description\":\"example description.\",\"start_date
\":\"2014-10-10\",\"mark\":255,\"id\":975},{\"added_by\":\"Ani\",\"description
\":\"example description..\",\"start_date\":\"2014-10-10\",\"mark\":255,\"id\":980
}]"}
```

receiving method-

```
$.getJSON("url",
                {var : Val},
                function(data){
                    here...
```

All I want is to count the JSON objects in this array. In the above case I want an length output as 2 but I'm not getting it.
I have tried below things-

1. `data.jList.length` -- < giving 200 like something as output
2. `Object.keys(data).length` -- < giving 200 like something as output
3. `Object.keys(data['jList']).length` -- < giving 1 as output

How do I get 2 as length output of the above array?

Comment: Can you add your controller code here? So it will good if we set it from code-behind.

Comment: Open your developer console (F12 in most browsers) and use `console.log(theVariable);` to see what it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jList` property of the object is just a string, so you need to convert it to a Javascript object using `JSON.parse()`.

```js
// Dummy of your "data" variable
var data = {"jList":"[{\"added_by\":\"Ani\",\"description\":\"example description.\",\"start_date \":\"2014-10-10\",\"mark\":255,\"id\":975},{\"added_by\":\"Ani\",\"description \":\"example description..\",\"start_date\":\"2014-10-10\",\"mark\":255,\"id\":980 }]"};

var myList = JSON.parse(data.jList);
alert(myList.length); // Alerts "2"
```

Comment: what do we do by parsing the data here? i have explicitly defined in the controller that the return datatype should be json.

Comment: @user3378974 Your return type IS JSON. Just so happens that whatever method is producing the JSON is sending the `jList` property as a string. That's a server-side issue, not client-side. If your return type wasn't JSON, you wouldn't be able to do `data.jList`, it would return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`"jList":"[{\"added_by\":\"...` is not an array, it's a string (and that's why it's length is 456 or 200 if you change the question).

Remove the surrounding double-quotation marks for it to be an array. Then you'll have `Array.prototype.length`.

Comment: Thanks -1. Any reason?